# How to deal with private member accessor and collections?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, private-members, generic-interface

I have a class hierachy like this

```
public class A
{
    protected class B 
    {
        String Name { get; set; }
    }

    protected class C : KeyedCollection<String, B> 
    {
        // ...
    }

    protected C Collection { get; }

    // ...

    public A Copy () 
    {
        // Creates a deep copy of this instance.
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to write a unit test to compare if two instances of A have the same items B inside the property KeyedCollection. However, I'm not being able to perform a foreach loop into the A instances. What I had tried,

```
[TestClass]
public class TestClass
{
    public void ATest()
    {
        A original = new A();
        A copy = A.Copy();

        // ...

        A_Accessor originalAccessor = A_Accessor.AttachShadow(original);
        A_Accessor copyAccessor = A_Accessor.AttachShadow(copy);

        foreach(var originalItem in originalAccessor.Collection)
        {
            var copyItem = copyAccessor[originalItem.Name];
            Assert.AreEqual(originalItem, copyItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't even compile because the C class accessor doesn't implements the IEnumerable interface (it doesn't implement any interface from KeyedCollection class). Does anyone have an idea about how can I overcome this issue?

The error message I'm getting is

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'C' because 'A_Accessor.C' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to compile your example: As expected I got an Error

`Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'A.C' is less accessible than field 'A.Collection'`.

Basically that means that you cannot declare a protected property using a private type. So it's not a problem with your test code but with the code to be tested ...

**EDIT**

You could use `originalAccessor.Collection.Target` and cast it to `ICollection`. Of course you can only enumerate over `object`s in this case, so you'll have to cast each item again:

```
foreach (var item in (originalAccessor.Collection.Target as ICollection)) {
   A_Accessor.B casted = A_Accessor.B.AttachShadow(item);
   var copyItem = copyAccessor[casted.Name];
   Assert.AreEqual(casted, copyItem);
}
```

Comment: The original code was incorrect. I've update it. Both classes, B and C are protected not private.

Comment: One more information, the compilation error I'm getting is on the foreach loop line.

Comment: I found a solution very similar to yours. The statement var copyItem = copyAccessor[casted.Name] will not work, because the C_Accessor doesn't implement an indexer of type String. I overcame it by using the First extension method with a predicate for return the correct item. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you're managing to expose a private class type via a protected property to start with, but as C *derives from* `KeyedCollection` it should already inherit the implementation of `IEnumerable<B>`.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but you should still be able to iterate over the collection... if you can even see the property. I suspect your code doesn't compile for other reasons - because `C` is declared in terms of a private member type, despite being protected, and because you're trying to access `C` from a different class in the first place (despite it being protected).

Comment: You are right about exposing a private class via a protected member. I wrote the code directly here, instead of copying and paste because I need to remove many unnecessary stuff from the original code. However, the classes are both protected. I'm updating the post.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to test if the copy method created a deep copy of A instance. But I'm experiencing some difficult to compare the the state members of A class from the unit test because the accessor classes generated by Visual Studio doesn't behave as expected. For example the C_Accessor class does't have an indexer of type String.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution I found was very similiar to Martin's suggestion:

```
var originalItems = 
    from item in (originalAccessor.Collection.Target as IEnumerable).Cast<Object>()
    select A_Accessor.B.AttachShadow(item);

var copyItems = 
    from item in (copyAccessor.Collection.Target as IEnumerable).Cast<Object>()
    select A_Accessor.B.AttachShadow(item); 

foreach(var original in originalItems) 
{ 
    String originalName = original.Name;
    A_Accessor.B copy = copyItems.First(b => b.Name == originalName);

    // ...
}
```

Thanks for all your assitance!
Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are testing an implementation detail, not the intended API level for users of your library.